# how to stop swipe , If only one image in flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Is there any way to stop swipe functionality with flexslider. If inserted image is only one.
like :

```
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      touch: $('.flexslider li').length > 1
   });
```

Comment: What happens if you swipe when only one image is present ? Flexbox must have taken care of that already..

Comment: but client doesn't want that

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got the solution:

```
if ($('#flexslider').length > 0) {
    var Len = $('#flexslider li').length;
    var Len;
    if(Len >1){
        swipe = true;
    }
    else{
       swipe = false;   
    }
    $('#flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        touch:swipe,
        after: function(slide) {
            //console.log(slider....);
        }

    });
}
```